# Disable image rotation on Tesseract

Tags: linux, command-line, rotation, tesseract

I'm convert TIF images to PDF files with Tesseract text recognition. If in the TIF-image is little recognizable text, the page is rotated 90 or 180 degrees.

**Is it possible to just turn rotation off in Tesseract?**

I am running Tesseract from command line with Ubuntu 18.04. Command is a direct copy of the Tesseract documentation.

```
tesseract img_001.tif -l fin --psm 3 img_001 pdf
```

Installed Tesseract version

```
$ tesseract --version
tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1
 leptonica-1.75.3
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0

 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

*Thanks for your help*

Comment: There were some discussions about it: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/GAbzk9BTGDE
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1165

Comment: I did not find a solution. I got the impression that there is a similar problem to mine that may be due to the exif data in the images. My TIFF images are scanned and the scanner software does not store any exif information.

Comment: In https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/issues/251, a commentor suggests ImageMagick's `convert -auto-orient`.